# Controlling swipeability of a notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is it possible to post a notification which if displayed on the lock screen cannot be swiped away by the user, but it can be swiped away if accessed via the notification bar?

(This is for Lollipop)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such API, so the answer is no, it's not possible.